# Approximate convolution of independent Beta variates?

Tags: probability-distributions, approximation, convolution

Is there a way to approximate the convolution of Beta variables?

Specifically, I am trying to find an approximation to $g(x_0)$:

$$g(x_0) = \int \delta(x_0-\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i x_i) \prod_{i=1}^{n} f(\alpha_i,\beta_i;x_i)\mathrm{d}x_i$$

where $\delta(x)$ is the Dirac delta function and

$$f(\alpha_i,\beta_i;x_i)=\frac{x_i^{\alpha_i - 1}(1-x_i)^{\beta_i - 1}}{\mathrm{B}(\alpha_i,\beta_i)}$$

for $0\le x \le 1$, and $f(\alpha_i,\beta_i;x_i) = 0$ otherwise.

For example, it is known that the convolution of Gamma functions can be approximated by another Gamma function, whose mean and variance is the sum of the mean and variances of the convoluted Gamma distributions (1). Is there a similar result for the convolution of Beta distributed variables?

(1) Stewart, T., Strijbosch, L., Moors, H., & Batenburg, P. van. (2007). A simple approximation to the convolution of Gamma distributions.

Comment: The function $g(x_0)$ does not contain a convolution, but the joint density of independent non-identical betas, which is just the product of the marginals. The paper you site is concerned with the distribution of the sum of independent gammas, which is a serial convolution on the joint density indeed -but again, your function does not contain a convolution on the joint density, just the joint density itself. Please clarify.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I am sorry, but I don't understand your concern. I have added the limits to the sum and product, I hope that makes it clearer. The expression I gave for $g(x_0)$ is a generalization of a convolution. It is a convolution if $a_i = 1$ for all $i$. Don't you agree?

Comment: $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function/measure?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Yes. I edited to make that explicit.

Comment: Thanks for the alert, but shouldn't you migrate this rather than re-post it?